# Updating Objects To Add New Element With .push

Tags: javascript, object, push

In the snippet below the goal is to check if the `addedPlayer` already exist in `players` by checking the `.name` property

**if** `addedPlayer` is already in `players` : Give the player a point

**else** update `players` by adding in `addedPlayer` with a starting point

```
let players = []

let addedPlayer = { 

   name: /* The Given Name To Check in players */ ,
   points: 1

}

function addPlayer(playerList, playerToAdd){

   const existingPlayers = playerList.map((playerToAdd) => playerToAdd.name);

   if(existingPlayers.includes(playerToAdd.name)){

       playerToAdd.points++

   } else {

      playerList.push(playerToAdd)

   }
}

addPlayer(players, addedPlayer)

console.log(players)
```

The problem is `players` only returns `addedPlayer`. My Goal being that `players` will store every new player and adds points accordingly

Comment: Your code works just fine, except for the part, where it is supposed to increase points as you're incrementing `playerToAdd.points` which you never store to your `playerList`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by finding if the `newPlayer` already exists in the given array by checking against `player.name` then conditionally incrementing `player.point` if `newPlayer` already exists else adding the `newPlayer` to the array.

Here is an example.

```js
let players = [
    {
        name: 'Player1',
        point: 1
    },
    {
        name: 'Player2',
        point: 2
    }
]

let newPlayer = { 
   name: 'Player2',
   points: 1
}

function addPlayer(playerlist, newPlayer) {
    // idx will be -1 if a player does not exist in playerlist by the name
    const idx = playerlist.findIndex(p => p.name === newPlayer.name);

    if (idx === -1) {
        // if you want to mutate the original array you can use playerlist.push(newPlayer) then return immediately from the function and omit the next return line
        return [...playerlist, newPlayer]
    }
    
    // increment player.point if newPlayer already exists

    playerlist[idx] = {...playerlist[idx], point: playerlist[idx].point + 1}
    // if you want to mutate the original array then omit the next return line
    return [...playerlist]
}

// because newPlayer already exists in players array by name calling the function addPlayer will increment player.point in players array where player.name is 'Player2'
console.log(addPlayer(players, newPlayer))

// calling the function with a player that does not exist in the array
let anotherPlayer = { name: 'Player3', point: 0 };

// anotherPlayer will be added to the returned array
console.log(addPlayer(players, anotherPlayer))
```

P.S. - The current solution will return a new array on each call of the `addPlayer` function if your use case requires you to mutate the array you can use `Array.prototype.push` and omit the returns from the function. I have included some comments in the snippet for more details.

Comment: Got it! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

It's considered good practice to always initialize our variables. I just created a name variable for our user object.

Each time you run addPlayer it will now push new players to the list.

```
let players = []
var name = "";

let addedPlayer = {

    name: name,
    points: 1

}

function addPlayer(playerList, playerToAdd) {

    const existingPlayers = playerList.map((playerToAdd) => playerToAdd.name);

    if (existingPlayers.includes(playerToAdd.name)) {

        playerToAdd.points++

    } else {

        playerList.push(playerToAdd)

    }
}

addPlayer(players, addedPlayer)

console.log(players)
```